# Is it possible to cancel out the nested $\arccos$ inside the $\cos$ and $\sin$ in this expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse-function, inverse-trigonometric-functions

I have the expression $\sqrt{\frac{23 + 16 × \sqrt{2}}{68}} × \sin\left(a × \arccos\left(\frac{\sqrt{8} - 1}{4}\right)\right) - \frac{1}{2} × \cos\left(a × \arccos\left(\frac{\sqrt{8} - 1}{4}\right)\right)$. I'd like to get rid of the $\arccos$ inside the regular trig functions if possible, but the extra $a$ variable inside the trig functions is confounding me.

I know that $\cos(\arccos(x)) = x$ and that $\sin(\arccos(x)) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ (over the domain $-1 ≤ x ≤ 1$, at least), but is it possible to similarly cancel the regular and inverse trig functions when there's an extra factor inside the regular trig function but outside the inverse function?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the answer is no; you cannot cancel the inverse and regular functions in the presence of a scale factor in the argument. For example, if $a=2$,
\begin{align}\sin\left(2\arccos\left(\frac{\sqrt{8} - 1}{4}\right)\right)&=2\sin\left(\arccos\left(\frac{\sqrt{8} - 1}{4}\right)\right)\cos\left(\arccos\left(\frac{\sqrt{8} - 1}{4}\right)\right)\\&=\frac{2\sqrt{2}-1}{4}\sqrt{1-\frac{(2\sqrt{2}-1)^2}{16}}\end{align}
By the double-angle formula.

Answer (score 0):

Some simplification possible another way, arccos is abbreviated but still included:

$$\frac{1}{1} \sin\left(a × \arccos\left(\frac{\sqrt{8} - 1}{4}\right)\right) - \frac{1}{2} × \cos\left(a × \arccos\left(\frac{\sqrt{8} - 1}{4}\right)\right)\tag 1$$

$$ \text{Let}\cos \alpha =\frac{1}{\sqrt {5}}, \sin \alpha =\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}, t=\arccos\left(\frac{\sqrt{8} - 1}{4}\right), hypo= \sqrt {5}/2 $$

First expression is
$$\frac{1}{1} \sin at  - \frac{1}{2} \cos at \tag 2$$
$$\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt 5} \sin at  - \frac{1}{\sqrt 5} \cos at\right) hypo \tag 3$$
$$\left(\sin \alpha \sin at  - \cos \alpha \cos at\right) hypo \tag 4$$

$$- hypo \cos(at+\alpha)    \tag 5$$